# .replace(' ', '-') will only replace first whitespace

Tags: javascript, replace

i am trying

To convert: `'any string separated with blankspaces'` into

```
'any-string-separated-with-blankspaces'
```

i am tying with  `.replace(' ','-')` but it would only replace first... why? how can i replace all?

http://jsfiddle.net/7ycg3/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a regular expression for that

```
.replace(/\s/g,'-')
```

`\s` will replace any kind of white-space character. If you're strictly after a "normal" whitespace use

`/ /g`

instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a regular expression as the first parameter, using the `/g` modifier to make it replace all occurrences:

```
var replaced = input.replace(/ /g,'-');
```

If you want to replace any whitespace character instead of a literal space, you need to use `\s` instead of  in the regex; and if you want to replace any number of consecutive spaces with *one* hyphen, then add `+` after the  or `\s`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not stated particularly clearly in [the MDN docs for `String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), but `String.replace` only does one replacement, unless the `g` flag is included in it, using a regular expression rather than a string:

> To perform a global search and replace, either include the `g` switch in the regular expression or if the first parameter is a string, include `g` in the flags parameter.

(But be aware that the `flags` parameter is non-standard, as they also note there.)

Thus, you want `tag.replace(/ /g,'-')`.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/7ycg3/1/

Use regex with `/g` modifier

Answer (score 0):

Use `/\s/g` inplace of `' '` in your question